# Complex hypersurface globally defined

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $A$ be a pure one-codimensional analytic subset of a domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$.
Is it true that $A$ is defined by one single holomorphic equation $f(z)=0$ if $D$ is bounded and pseudo-convex ?

Comment: or more generally $A$ is a hypersurface in a Stein complex manifold $M$.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true that given a hypersurface $A\subset M$ of a Stein manifold there exists a global holomorphic function $f\in \mathcal O(M)$ whose zero locus is $A$.
The relevant notion is that of divisor: the hypersurface $A$ defines a holomorphic (= positive) divisor and your question is whether that divisor is solvable i.e. is the zero set of some global holomorphic function.
This is called the Cousin-II problem and it has a nice soluton in terms of cohomology:
The divisor $A$ defines a line bundle $\mathcal O(A)$ and the divisor has a global equation $f\in \mathcal O(M)$ if and only if the line bundle has zero first Chern class : $c_1(\mathcal O(A))=0\in H^2(M,\mathbb Z)$.
One can show that every  Stein manifold with $H^2(M,\mathbb Z)\neq0 $ actually has a non solvable  positive divisor.

All this is beautifully explained in [L. Kaup-B.Kaup's excellent book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Holomorphic_Functions_of_Several_Variabl.html?id=nDgBsOurnAIC&redir_esc=y) and the last sentence comes from their Proposition 54.6.

**Edit**
A completely explicit but a bit complicated example of a hypersurface without global equation in a Stein manifold is given in [this  book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461298768) by Grauert-Fritzche on pages 172-174.

Comment: Ok thank you.
I am going to check this book.

Is it possible to find an explicit example of such hypersurface which is not globally defined in a polydisk for example ?

Comment: No, because in a polydisk $H^2(M,\mathbb Z)=0$ .

Comment: Thank you.
Actually there exists bounded pseudoconvex domains such that $H^2(M,ℤ) = ℤ$.
Take $D= \{z\in C^3 ; |z^2_1 +z^2_2 + z^2_3 - 1 | < 1\}$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, Mister Godfrey. And, yes your example is correct: it is due to Serre (1953) and the hypersurface without equation is any connected component of the intersection of the domain  with the complex plane $z_2=iz_1$ .

Comment: The domain is not bounded but by taking the intersection of $D$ with a polydisk one obtains the contrexemple.

Comment: Finally, I think I have a complete answer, following Grauert-Fritzsche,  L. Kaup-B.Kaup and Shabat :
In general a pure one codimensional analytic set in a domain of holomorphy $D$ is not globally defined by one single equation $f(z)=0$ (see the previous contrexemples).
But the statement is true if H²(D,Z)=0.
However by using sheaf theory one has the following:
If A is analytic in a domain of holomorphy D there exists n+1 holomorphic functions on $D$ such that
$A= \{ f_1(z)=\dots=f_{n+1}(z)=0 \}$ (see Grauert-Fritzsche)