# How to tell if a simply-connected curve is the complex plane or disk

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose I have an analytic function $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ whose zero locus $V=\{(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : f(z,w)=0\}$ is smooth and simply connected. By uniformization, $V$ is conformally equivalent to either $\mathbb{C}$ or the open unit disk $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$. But which one? Is this "easily" determined by some properties of the function $f$?

Comment: Do you know any examples where it's the upper half-plane? I have a suspicion that it might always be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There do exist proper holomorphic embeddings of the open unit disk into $\mathbb{C}^2$ (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0791). And I'm under the impression that every smooth, codimension one holomorphic submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is the zero locus of a holomorphic function. Is this off?

Comment: Did you check Ahlfors and Sario "Riemann Surfaces"? They spend considerable effort on discussing the problem of type for Riemann surfaces, check if they consider the case of complex curves given as subvarieties in $C^2$.

Comment: As for your question if a complex curve in $C^2$ can be defined via a single equation, the answer is positive, since $H^2(C^2, {\mathbb Z})=0$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237192/complex-hypersurface-globally-defined.

Comment: Here is an easy example of a holomorphic embedding of the unit disc into $\mathbb{C}^2$:  take a complex torus $T$ with $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(T) = 2$ and any holomorphic curve curve $C \subset T$ of genus $g >2$ (for example, one might take $g = 2$ and $T$ to be the Jacobian of $T$).
The holomorphic map $C \to T$ induces a holomorphic map of universal coverings: $\tilde{C} = \Delta \to \mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: ... moreover, I suspect, one can define the image of $\Delta = \tilde{C}$ by a single equation. To do this one can realize $C$ as a vanishing locus for a holomorphic $2$-form  on $T$. The pull-back of this form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ can be written as $fdz\wedge dw$, where $f$ is a certain "modular form" on $\mathbb{C}^2$. Its zero locus is precisely the pre-image of $C \subset T$.